# pip3 not working on ubuntu 20.04: "has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-20.04

On Ubuntu 20.04 i have installed pip3 with the following command:
`sudo apt install python3-pip`

But when I run `pip3` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

In a virtual-environment the `pip3` command works fine however.

As suggested in other SO answers I have tried reinstalling python3 and pip3, all without success. A lot of other answers use pip3 to solve the problem, but I'm unable to run pip3.

I have noticed that several other programs (docker-compose, Guake) give me a similar error.

I run python 3.8.2. And when I open an virtual-environment I can see that my pip3 version is 20.0.2.

Comment: I feel your pain.  Sometimes I have success being more explicit, ie calling `pip3.8`.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! No success unfortunately: command not found

Comment: have you tried `python3.8 -m pip` ?

Comment: `python3.8 -m pip --version` gives me `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Answer (score 2):

I came a long way to fixing this, but in the end I went with a fresh install. I'll share here what I learned, hoping it can help somebody else.

My hypothesis is that it went wrong when I accidentaly installed a requirements.txt without being in an virtual environment. That triggered the installation of an old *setuptools*, which then broke pip and ruined everything.

Possible fix could be:

1. Remove pip: `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python3-pip`
2. Install pip via python: `python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`. Now pip works again.
3. Now try to fix setuptools: `pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed setuptools`. Fix the issues that pop here (how? don't know). An issue I had here was that I was not allowed to call pip with sudo.
4. In the end I guess you'll want pip installed the normal way, so you uninstall `python3.8 -m pip uninstall pip` and install `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Next time I'll skip installing python3-pip completely. That way I'm forced to open a virtual environment.

In the end, several issues starting popping up (also because I tinkered around a lot) and I just lost faith in my installation. Even if I would fix it all, I knew that when the next issue would pop up I would again feel like this might be the problem. Better to start fresh and have a solid base.